# Grab the next N items in a loop

Tags: javascript

How do I grab the next N items in a for loop. So for example, on every iteration, grab the current item and the next N items.

```
let arr = [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g ]
```

Say N = 3, on each iteration:

```
a b c
b c d
c d e
```

and so on..

Comment: Have you tried something? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate from 0 to `n` and [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the elements in that specific range (index, index+`n`):

```js
let arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' ]
let a = [], n = 3;
for(let i = 0; i+n < arr.length; i++) a.push(arr.slice(i, i+n));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: wow that's the quickest I've seen someone answer a question

Answer (score -1):

```
let n = 3;
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    let temp = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        temp.push(array[j])
    }
    arr.push(temp)
}
```